# Why draw threejs object in mapbox,has many mesh sawtooth?

Tags: three.js, mapbox

I use customlayer interface draw threejs object. But it has many sawtooth
but I find a plugin (threebox), can draw object in mapbox, and it draw smooth. Like this image

[image]

In this pic, higher yellow ball is created by my code, it has many sawtooth. The lower red ball is threebox created by threebox, it's smooth.
What happened in there? I look the threebox sourcecode, can't found different with my code.

I put my code on JSBin.this is link
https://jsbin.com/remometaze/1/edit?html,js,output
please take a look and help me,thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- mapboxgl -->
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.7.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.7.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />  

    <!-- echarts -->
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.6.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts-gl@1.1.1/dist/echarts-gl.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="echarts.min.385.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="echarts-gl-master.m.js"></script> -->

    <!-- 其他 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="assets/world.js"></script> -->

    <!-- 百度地图 -->
    <!-- <script src="https://gallerybox.echartsjs.com/dep/echarts/latest/extension/bmap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://api.map.baidu.com/api?v=3.0&ak=9Y5hSOZKKo9QcWrwag0qMYYvQ6PIKEzw"></script> -->
    <style>
        body,
        html,
        #map {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map" class='map'></div>

    <!-- <script src="echartsopt.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="three3.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.106.2/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.link/repo/peterqliu/threebox/master/dist/threebox.js"></script>    
  <!-- <script src="mapboxopt.js" type="module"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="mapboxopt.js"></script> -->
    <script src="mapboxextrude.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="3dmodel.js"></script> -->
<script>
    var __mapcenter__ = [116.582, 35.415];
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaG91eGlleXUiLCJhIjoiY2pldjE5amU3NndzeDM5bzd5bm9ncDgycyJ9.j1F-Lgid3L5k2Abm8_xTeQ';

var mapboxgl_style = 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10';
var tb;
function addTB(mapd, gl) {
    tb = new Threebox(
        mapd,
        gl,
        { defaultLights: true }
    );
    var sphere = tb.sphere({radius:1, color: 'red', material: 'MeshStandardMaterial' })
        .setCoords(__mapcenter__.concat([500]));
    // add sphere to the scene
    tb.add(sphere);
}
const linetype = 0;//0=normal 1=fat
// var map = myChart.getModel().getComponent('mapbox3D').getMapbox();
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: mapboxgl_style,
    zoom: 16,
    center: __mapcenter__,
    pitch: 20,
    antialias: true // create the gl context with MSAA antialiasing, so custom layers are antialiased
});


$.ajaxSettings.async = false;
var linesdata;
$.getJSON('jp4data.json',
    function (res) {
        linesdata = res;
    });
// configuration of the custom layer for a 3D model per the CustomLayerInterface
function initThree(_this, mapd) {
    _this.camera = new THREE.Camera();
    _this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    // create two three.js lights to illuminate the model
    // var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    // directionalLight.position.set(0, -70, 100).normalize();
    // this.scene.add(directionalLight);

    // var directionalLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    // directionalLight2.position.set(0, 70, 100).normalize();
    // this.scene.add(directionalLight2);
    const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    _this.scene.add(directionalLight);
    _this.map = mapd;
}
var lineGroup;
var mbpt = mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(
    __mapcenter__,
    0
);
var threescale= mbpt.meterInMercatorCoordinateUnits();
var customLayer = {
    id: '3d-model',
    type: 'custom',
    renderingMode: '3d',
    onAdd: function (mapd, gl) {
        initThree(this, mapd);
        addTB(mapd, gl);
        //绘制光源
        addLight(this.scene);
        //绘制飞线
        // drawLines(this.scene);
        //绘制建筑物
        // drawBuildings(this.scene);
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            canvas: mapd.getCanvas(),
            antialias: true,
            alpha:true,
            context: gl,
            antialias: true
        });

        this.renderer.autoClear = false;
    },
    render: function (gl, matrix) {
        // updateLight();
        tb.update();
        // updateLines();
        this.camera.projectionMatrix =new THREE.Matrix4().fromArray(matrix);// m.multiply(l);
        this.renderer.state.reset();
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
        this.map.triggerRepaint();
    }
};

map.on('style.load', function () {
    addMapboxExtrudeLayer();
    map.addLayer(customLayer);
});
// used to determine the switch point for the light animation
var invert = 1;
var phase = 0;
var pointColor, pointLight, sphereLight, sphereLightMaterial, sphereLightMesh
function addLight(scene) {
    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff ) );
    var sunlight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.25);
    sunlight.position.set(0,80000000,100000000);
    sunlight.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;
    scene.add(sunlight);

    pointColor = "#ccffcc";
    pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(pointColor);
    pointLight.distance = 0.1;
    scene.add(pointLight);
    var pt = mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(
        __mapcenter__,
        600
    );
    var met = pt.meterInMercatorCoordinateUnits();
    // add a small sphere simulating the pointlight
    sphereLight = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(30,120,120);
    sphereLightMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xac6c25 });
    sphereLightMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereLight, sphereLightMaterial);
    // sphereLightMesh.castShadow = true;

    sphereLightMesh.position.set(pt.x, pt.y, pt.z);
    sphereLightMesh.scale.set(threescale,threescale,threescale);
    console.log(sphereLightMesh)
    scene.add(sphereLightMesh);
}
/**
  * @desc 经纬度转换成墨卡托投影
  * @param {array} 传入经纬度
  * @return array [x,y,z]
  */
function lnglatToMector(lnglat) {
    var pt = mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat(
        lnglat,
        0
    );
    const { x, y, z } = pt;
    return [x, y, z];
}

function mercatorConvert(fts) {
    fts.forEach(d => {
        d.vector3 = [];
        d.geometry.coordinates.forEach((coordinates, i) => {
            d.vector3[i] = [];
            coordinates.forEach((c, j) => {
                if (c[0] instanceof Array) {
                    d.vector3[i][j] = [];
                    c.forEach(cinner => {
                        let cp = lnglatToMector0(cinner);
                        d.vector3[i][j].push(cp);
                    });
                } else {
                    let cp = lnglatToMector0(c);
                    d.vector3[i].push(cp);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
/**
 * @desc 绘制地图模型 points 是一个二维数组 [[x,y], [x,y], [x,y]]
 */
function drawModel(points) {
    // console.log(points)
    const shape = new THREE.Shape();
    points.forEach((d, i) => {
        const [x, y] = d;
        if (i === 0) {
            shape.moveTo(x, y);
        } else if (i === points.length - 1) {
            shape.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x, y);
        } else {
            shape.lineTo(x, y, x, y);
        }
    });

    var extrudeSettings = {
        depth: -0.01,
        bevelEnabled: false,
    };
    const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, extrudeSettings);

    // var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x156289, emissive: 0x072534,  } );
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: '#006de0',
        // transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.8,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    return mesh;
}
var projection;
function lnglatToMector0(lnglat) {
    if (!projection) {
        projection = d3
            .geoMercator()
            .center([116.582, 35.415])
            .scale(800)
            // .rotate(Math.PI / 4)
            .translate([0.75, 0.7]);
    }
    const [y, x] = projection([...lnglat]);
    let z = 0;
    return [x, y, z];
}


var shines = [];
// var colors = ['#FFCCCC', '#FFFF99', '#CCCCFF'];
var colors = ['#FF6666', '#FFFF00', '#0066CC'];

function addMapboxExtrudeLayer() {
    map.addSource("buildings", {
        // type: "geojson",
        // data: buildingjson,
        type: "vector",
        "url": "mapbox://houxieyu.as833g2t",
    });
    map.addLayer({
        'id': '3dbuildings',
        // 'source': 'buildings',
        'source': 'buildings',
        'source-layer': 'jiningbuildings-7kbdau',
        'type': 'fill-extrusion',
        'minzoom': 0,
        'paint': {
            'fill-extrusion-height': ["get", "height"],// ["*", 3, ["to-number",["get", "hegiht"]]],
            'fill-extrusion-color':
                // ["get", "ftcolor"]
                // ["case", ["to-boolean", ["feature-state", "cc"]], ["feature-state", "cc"], colors[2]]
                ["case", ["to-boolean", ["feature-state", "cc"]], ["case", ["feature-state", "shine"], ["feature-state", "cc"], colors[2]], colors[2]]
        }
    });
    initShine();
    var ystimer = setInterval(function () {

        //闪烁版
        shines.forEach(function (id) {
            var state = map.getFeatureState({
                id: id,
                source: 'buildings',
                'sourceLayer': 'jiningbuildings-7kbdau'
            });
            state.delay += 1;
            if (state.shine) {
                if (state.delay > 4) {
                    state.delay = 0;
                    state.shine = false;
                    // state.cc = colors[2];
                }
            }
            else {
                if (state.delay > 2) {
                    state.delay = 0;
                    state.shine = true;
                    // state.cc = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
                }
            }
            map.setFeatureState({
                id: id,
                source: 'buildings',
                'sourceLayer': 'jiningbuildings-7kbdau'
            }, state);
        })
    }, 200);
}

var curfts = [];
map.on('data', '3dbuildings', function () {
    // curfts = map.queryRenderedFeatures('buildings');
});

function initShine() {
    shines = [];
    var maxid = 10000;
    for (let i = 0, l = maxid / 20; i < l; i++) {
        let inx = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxid);
        shines.push(inx);
        map.setFeatureState({
            id: inx,
            source: 'buildings',
            'sourceLayer': 'jiningbuildings-7kbdau'
        }, {
            cc: colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)],
            delay: Math.floor(Math.random() * 4),
            shine: true
        });
    }
}

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

——向战斗在武汉前线的英雄医护人员致以最崇高的问候

Comment: Threebox is doing WAAAY more stuff than your code. Can you just use threebox?

Comment: I dont user threebox.I just want to find the reason of sawtooth,why threebox no sawtooth,My code has many sawtooth.Compare the source code,I cant find different between my code and threebox.

Comment: It looks like threebox is including its own copy of threejs v94 .. maybe try using that version in your code so they will match?